# focal 20.04 kernel src missing files

Tags: 20.04, kernel, raspberrypi

index;

[https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+git/focal/](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux-raspi/+git/focal/)

path;

root/scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders.c

code;

```
line 18 #include "classmap.h"
line 19 #include "initial_sid_to_string.h"
```

Where are these files?

Edit:
After installing libselinux1-dev package. I am getting same error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550695/error-compiling-the-linux-kernel

Comment: thanks, I missed that selinux dependencies need for building kernel